# Sort order when loading related objects using selectinload in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

Is there a way to specify the sort order when loading related objects using the `selectinload` option in SQLAlchemy?

My SQLAlchemy version: 1.2.10
My python version: 3.6.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is just to specify the default ordering of the relationship in your mapped class. In the example below, a query like `query(Example).options(selectinload(Example.related_items))` would order the eager loaded related items by the `id` column.

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

Base = declarative_base()

class Example(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'examples'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    related_items = relationship('RelatedItem', back_populates='example', order_by='RelatedItem.id')

class RelatedItem(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'related_items'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    example_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('examples.id'), nullable=False)
    example = relationship('Example', back_populates='related_items')
```

Comment: Is there a method to override this default for a query?

Comment: @Kohver - I think this question is what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32828849/sqlalchemy-override-relationship-defined-order-by-in-a-query