# Limiting returned records on a selectinload SQLAlchemy relationship

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, marshmallow

Basing this question off this [similar post, but about SORT ORDER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52582163/sort-order-when-loading-related-objects-using-selectinload-in-sqlalchemy)
I understand that you can change the `lazy` to `dynamic` in the relatonship, and then that will allow you to query against the relationship before loading, but is there a way to LIMIT the return results directly from a `selectin` or on of the other loading techniques?

Use case is, Im trying to pass the record into Marshmallow and limit the number of nested records returned. `dynamic` at that point doesnt work, as Marshmallow includes it as an `all()` and `selectin` appears to just included it unqueryable at time of load, and again Marshmallow get the entire record set.

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

Base = declarative_base()

class Example(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'examples'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    related_items = relationship('RelatedItem', back_populates='example', order_by='RelatedItem.id')

class RelatedItem(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'related_items'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    example_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('examples.id'), nullable=False)
    example = relationship('Example', back_populates='related_items')
```